# Import nk2 file to Outlook 2010 with roaming profiles, on locked-down clients

Tags: windows-7, outlook-2010, roaming-profile

We recently moved a bunch of end users over to Office 2010 on Windows 7 from Office 2007 on Windows XP and I am having an issue getting their nk2 files to prepopulate their Outlook caches.

I moved the nk2 files from their PC and put them onto the file server where their roaming profiles are saved.

The VMs that the users are connecting to [through thin clients] are locked down by GPO, so I cannot simply run an Outlook/importnk2 and have it merge with the Outlook 2010 autocomplete cache.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish do this for a number of users with these constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems cmd prompt was accessible through the menus after all.   Was able to move their nk2 to their logged in VM's C drive remotely them run outlook with switch /importnk2.  After that,  their autocomplete updated.

Answer (score 0):

Ideas, yes, but it depends on what you mean by locked down, how many users, and what other resources you have.

The imported NK2 file basically creates a "Suggested Contacts" folder (or rather, adds to it).  So you can import by having the users log in on another system that isn't logged down (create a temporary system to do this for them.  Once imported, they should be available on all systems).

Another suggestion - not sure this will work - create a group policy script to run as the user that auto-starts outlook with the appropriate switch to import the nk2 file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Gpo blocks access to cmd/run so I can't do an import nk2.  The users are using completely new roaming profiles opposed to formerly used local on their Pcs.  I'll have to see about creating a relaxed VD for them to log into just for their initial outlook login if the admins can't come up with something more fluid.   Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the GPO blocking USER access to Run/cmd may not apply to a LOGIN script processed in a group policy file.  Haven't tested, but you could...